# In the SEDE sidebar, give the "i" icon (show table contents) a larger hitbox

Tags: feature-request, design, data-explorer

Proposal: Give the `i` icon in the SEDE sidebar some horizontal padding for larger hitbox.

Currently, the `i` icon which shows the table contents for small enum-like tables has a small hitbox (particularly in the inline/horizontal dimension). It's a bit of a pain, any click that isn't exactly on the element will instead collapse/expand the column listing for the table.

Screenshot with blue highlighted hitbox courtesy of browser devtools:
[image: screenshot of the icon hitbox]

Comment: A 5-pixel hitbox does seem a tad curmudgeonly.